# Convert Nintex workflow and InfoPath form to MS Flow and PowerApps form

Tags: infopath, flow, powerapp, nintex

Is there a tool or process that will allow the converstion of Nintex workflows and InfoPath form to Microsoft Flow and PowerApps.
My initial thought is no; I will need to re-develop the application (both WF and Form), but thought I'd ask the community of any possible shortcuts.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good place to start is this [blog post](https://johnliu.net/blog/ninja-list-the-great-migration-of-sharepoint-workflow-to-power-automate), but the short answer is ... no. Now, when you read that post, you'll see at the bottom a link to a proof of concept app to convert spd workflows to flow. Not bad. And, for very simple workflows that might even be great. But the reality is that for intermediate level flows or up, you'll often need to go back to the requirements and then design the forms and workflows based on that.

Sorry that sounds like a lot, but going back to the requirements IS my shortcut, as trying to copy a workflow action by action is often a frustrating experience.